# enrollment request missing key usage of MDM of windows phone

Tags: mdm

I'm trying to make my policy service and enrollment service work with one standalone CA server.The policy service and enrollment service are implemented by myself. The policy service is very simple of which the reponse is the same as what the document described.The  enrollment service just forwards the RST to standalone CA server. I use HttpWebRequest to simulate the process that issue certificate in web browser and get the certificate successfully. The problem is the certificate request wp device generated which is pkcs#10 request doesn't include the Key Usage and Extended Key Usage. It results to the client certificate issued by CA doesn't include the Key Usage and Extended Key Usage which should be Digital Signature and Client Authentication. The DM client can't connect DM server due to this.

Anyone can tell me how to make device generate the certificate request including key usage and extended key usage?

it could be one workaround that edit the request in my enrollment service and add the missing key usage and extended key usage. But I don't know how to edit it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I also faced similar issue. I have raised one point in MSDN forum for this behavior. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97c4d435-024b-4565-8c44-d0afa62eabe9/windows-mdm-bulk-enrollment-flow-key-usage-not-coming-as-a-part-of-csr?forum=developingmdmsolutions

Answer (score 0):

What CA are you using to do this process?

I've been working on a similar process and trying to get my Windows Phone 8.0 to register against an ASP.NET WebAPI service, so I've written a simple CA process using C# and Bouncy Castle.

My work-in-progress code is on GitHub, it doesn't work yet for end-to-end MDM enrolment, but it does allow you to sign a request and set the key usage:

https://github.com/ShawInnes/MSMDM/blob/master/MSMDM.Test/BouncyCastleCACerts.cs

```
var usages = new[] { KeyPurposeID.IdKPServerAuth };
certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id,
                                  false, 
                                  new ExtendedKeyUsage(usages));
```